# What is the largest lateral surface area possible for a cylinder inscribed in a cone?

Tags: geometry

The radius of the base of a right circular cone is $14$ cm and altitude $20$ cm. What is the largest lateral surface area possible for a cylinder inscribed in this cone?

Actually I've tried to solve this one. Let the height , radius  of the largest possible cylinder  are $h \ $ and $ \ r$ respectively . Then considering the upper triangle and the total triangle , it comes

$\frac{20-h}{r}=\frac{20}{14} \ => 7h+10r=140  $

next what should be my approach to solve this one  ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Given your rep, you're probably familiar enough with the site to know that if you're posting what is obviously a homework question, you should either provide something interestingly non-obvious about it, or tell us where you're having a problem dealing with the question.

Comment: edited @stochasticboy321

Comment: Great. Now, you know the formula for the surface area in terms of $r$ and $h$. Feed the above relation in that to get surface area as a function of $r$. Can you find the maxima of this?

Comment: got it .. ..   easy one .. thanks for help

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the rant above, and please do add some context on your question the next time, so the community can differentiate you from freeloaders who want someone to do their homework for them without having to think about it first.